# Change font color based on background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website where there are images moving around in the background and I would like the nav font to change based on the image color..

To get what I mean, just look at the '+' in this website nav https://www.atomomanagement.com/

Based on the image it either is white or black. I would like to do the same but I had no luck. I tried using mix-blend-mode: difference but it does not work

Can anyone help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt I should post an answer to explain what is going on with OPs example.

Simply settings a `fill: white` on an SVG does not fully reproduce the desired result. OP's example also requires a parent div with `mix-blend-mode: difference` set as well.

You can actually reproduce this without any SVGs at all. You simply need an element with a color/fill of white, and a parent element with `mix-blend-mode: difference`. This has to do with how the blending mode of **difference** works with the color white over a background.

```js
function _Swap() {
  document.querySelector(".backgroundDiv").style.background = (document.querySelector(".backgroundDiv").style.background == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") ? "rgb(255, 255, 255)" : "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
}
```

```css
.backgroundDiv {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 4em;
}

.test {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

p {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundDiv">
  <div class="test">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Swap Background Color" onclick="_Swap()">
```

Comment: I understand your code but when I try to implement it in my website I am having issues. Here is the link to it https://pre.ottosuperstudio.com/derocchi/

As you can see, the "menu-voices" div has the mix-blend-mode: difference and the a links has color: white but when everything is white they don't turn black and I only see them when images comes below them (always white though)

Comment: @GhzNcl it looks like some sort of incompatibility with the style/CSS of another parent element. Try adding `mix-blend-mode: difference` to the **<div>** right above the **<div>** with `class="relative"`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not changing. the `path` element in `svg` has this `css` attribute:

```
fill: white;
```

It is causing what you see. you can open it in devTools and remove that attribute and you can see the change then. to achieve what you want make a svg and add `fill: white;` to the path element.

#### Update:

I just found out this css property which was given to `nav` tag:

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

It will revert the entire color of the element in the tag based on the bg.

> [essxtee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2339619/essxtee) answer was before my update. So the credit is his :)

Comment: Then for each text I want to do the same I should use svg? :)
If I disable it like you said then it just disappears though

Comment: @GhzNcl You can use text if you need to, you don't have to use an SVG for this. Having `fill: white` is just part of why this works. You can do the same having `color: white` on text elements as well. But you also must have a parent element with `mix-blend-mode: difference;` set. These two things allow the color to adapt to the background.